# How to fix: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid elementID: Length of the string: [1,255]. ASCII characters only. in agora.io SDK

Tags: web, agora.io

I updated my agora.io SDK from '2.4' to '3.0.2' and the message below appear on console log.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid elementID: Length of the string: [1,255]. ASCII characters only.
at s (AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2)
at Object.t.play (AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:8)
```

Anyone could help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly make sure that a string is passed inside your stream.play method.

If you are passing in your agora `uid` to `stream.play()`, make sure that your `uid` is a string or that you explicitly typecast it like this: `stream.play(String(uid))`

References:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#play